# Does shaheed (martyr) enter paradise immediately after they die?

Tags: jannah, death, martyr

Do they physically enter paradise after death or is it just spiritual experience?

Comment: Hello and welcome to [islam.se]. Could you split the question across multiple different questions and possibly link them up to provide context?

Comment: @user60180, dear-Bleeding Finger is right. seemingly, there are two separated questions in your question. I reckon that's why there is no response (till now) for your question. as Bleeding Finger mentioned, it is better to write them as two different questions... Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Imam Reza(a.s.) quoted from his fathers (ancestors) that Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) said:

> Shahid(martyre) is the initial person who enters the Janna (paradise)
>
> (Majmoo'eh Varam Vol.2, Pg.121 )

Of course I assume we ought to pay attention that seemingly there are two kinds of Heaven(paradise). A heaven which is related to Barzakh, and the other heaven which apparently is the main heaven and eventually good people will go there (after the Day of Judgment)
(so, seemingly, is has not mentioned that which paradise…)

I suggest you to see the site(source) below. So it consists of further info. Regarding Shahid.
(note: unfortunately this is a Persian site (not English), hence I hope it could help you anyhow)

---

**Source:**

- [www.mahallati.ghasam.ir](http://%20%20http://mahallati.ghasam.ir/h312/fa/news-details/25067/)